# Logstash - Error when try to run conf fle

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I try to run a conf file to use mysql database on input and on output I want to get a json-line. But an error is happening.

I'm putting the error and the conf file in this question.

```
Sending Logstash's logs to C:/logstash-6.0.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-12-13T17:33:43,978][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"C:/logstash-6.0.1/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-12-13T17:33:43,978][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"fb_apache", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x1896b5d @module_name="fb_apache", @directory="C:/logstash-6.0.1/modules/fb_apache/configuration", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
[2017-12-13T17:33:43,978][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"C:/logstash-6.0.1/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-12-13T17:33:43,978][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"netflow", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x18b75ca @module_name="netflow", @directory="C:/logstash-6.0.1/modules/netflow/configuration", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,038][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Reading pipeline configurations from YAML {:location=>"C:/logstash-6.0.1/config/pipelines.yml"}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,038][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,068][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Agent: Configuring metric collection
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,068][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,088][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,138][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,148][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,148][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] starting agent
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,158][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting puma
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,158][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9600}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,168][DEBUG [logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] Skipping the following files while reading config since they don't match the specified glob pattern {:files=>["C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/BCHARTS-MTGOXUSD.csv", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/cpdump", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/ingest-convert.sh", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash-plugin", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash-plugin.bat", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash.bat", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash.conf", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/logstash.lib.sh", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/ruby", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/setup.bat", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/system-install"]}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,178][DEBUG][logstash.api.service     ] [api-service] start
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,178][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] Reading config file {:config_file=>"C:/logstash-6.0.1/bin/db.conf"}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,208][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Converging pipelines
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,208][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Needed actions to converge {:actions_count=>1}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,218][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Executing action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,298][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,768][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"jdbc", :type=>"input", :class=>LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,778][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"ArgumentError", :message=>"invalid byte sequence in UTF-8", :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyString.java:2541:in `gsub'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/environment_variables.rb:28:in `replace_env_placeholders'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/environment_variables.rb:18:in `deep_replace'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:109:in `block in config_init'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:108:in `config_init'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inputs/base.rb:62:in `initialize'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152:in `plugin'", "(eval):8:in `<eval>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in `eval'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:82:in `initialize'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:215:in `initialize'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:35:in `execute'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:335:in `block in converge_state'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:332:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:319:in `converge_state'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in `block in converge_state_and_update'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in `converge_state_and_update'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in `execute'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:362:in `block in execute'", "C:/logstash-6.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,798][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] PeriodicPoller: Stopping
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,798][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] PeriodicPoller: Stopping
[2017-12-13T17:33:44,798][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] PeriodicPoller: Stopping
```

The conf file

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash-6.0.1\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM table"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug  }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the first row of the data

```
cod,cod_veiculo.cod_destino,cod_origem
5530041,16555,84661,1187
```

Comment: This is working for me maybe the data in the mysql table is having an issue. Could you paste the first row of the data in mysql.

Comment: @HatimStovewala I put the first row of the data. Is that how you want it?

Comment: Try with the query "select * from table limit 1;" and see what you get.

Comment: I get the same error. I try to run just the jdbc without settings, like that `input { jdbc {} } output { stdout {} }` and I get the same problem. This is so strange.

Comment: Try downloading the latest logstash zip package. I tried with version 6.1 and it works perfectly.

Comment: I tried,but the same problem happen:(

Comment: That's really strange. I tried on 2 variants(Windows & Linux), both works fine.

Comment: Worked on linux. I don´t now what is the problem.